# es6 object or other parameters destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Lets pretend I have a function that I want to be able to use in two ways:

```
movePoint("pointName", 32, 25)
```

Or

```
movePoint({
    name: "pointName",
    x: 32,
    y: 25,
    otherRarelyUsedParameter: true,
})
```

In the past, I would just check if the first parameter was a string, and if so; treat it as though the user inputted the first format; and if not, I assume its an object and work with it directly.

## Question

Could we achieve this sort of behaviour using any es6 magic. If I code for the first case I have:

```
function movePoint (name, x, y)
```

And for the second case I'd use:

```
function movePoint ({name, x, y, otherRarelyUsedParameter=true})
```

Is any way to perhaps keep the second syntax, whilst also allowing the first parameter to be a string.

If the answer is no, do you have any recommendations for what would be the most readable way to implement this?

Comment: Even if there is a way, aren't you worried that you'd be stuffing all this logic inside the arguments? To me this sounds like a non-readable/non-ideal approach that's just gonna make things messier only for the sake of using new lang. features.

Answer (score 3):

I think you really should not use overloads like this. But when you do, writing a second function is probably the simplest solution:

```
function movePoint (o, x, y) {
    if (typeof o == "string")
        return _movePoint({name: o, x, y});
    else
        return _movePoint(o);
}

function _movePoint ({name, x, y, otherRarelyUsedParameter=true}) {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two pieces of logic here, the logic of detecting input type, and the logic of moving a point.  This is best handled with two function:

```
function movePoint(nameOrSpec, x, y) {
    if (typeof nameOrSpec === "string") {
        return movePointInternal({
            name: nameOrSpec,
            x,
            y
        });
    } else {
        return movePointInternal(nameOrSpec);
    }
}

function movePointInternal({ name, x, y }) {
    // Do whatever the function needs to do
}
```

It is possible to do this with one function and destructuring, but it's not the preferred option in my opinion:

```
function movePoint({ name = arguments[0], x = arguments[1], y = arguments[2] }) {
    // Do function work with (name, x, y)
    console.log({ name, x, y });
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I figured I would do as well. I was just trying to do it in a more maintainable way :P If I end up with a library with 30+ functions like this, it tends to get unruly. If I don't get any other clever answers, I'll just go ahead and set this one correct :)

Comment: Notice that the destructuring will fail when one of the parameters is `length` or something which is a property of a string that gets passed.

Comment: @user2662833 Especially if you have so many functions, you probably should generate the wrapper functions dynamically

Comment: Can you elaborate on that note? I'm not sure what you mean by that.